# Change Firebase Auth from Google Single-sign-on to Email link on Android

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, google-oauth

I am trying to move from Google Single-sign-on to Email Link authentication for kids apps since, Google is not allowing use of its single-sign-on for kids apps.

I started with the Firebase Auth UI (for android). The login attempt fails saying: "Firebase login unsuccessful. Account linking failed due to provider not enabled by application". I assume this is because Google Auth provider is not enabled, which is how I want for the next update to the app. If I enable Google Auth as provider, then users can continue to sign in using Google, which I am trying to remove.

I had assumed the accounts would be linked automatically since it is the same email for signin. It does not appear to be the case. Is it a limitation of the Firebase Auth UI for Android, or of Firebase Authentication. If I built my own UI, will it link the accounts without signing in to Google?

Please advice on how to change auth type while keeping the email the same.

Comment: I believe the firebase UI does not include passwordless email authentication. I am trying the direct implementation

Comment: In theory, If a user has an existing Google sign in email with Firebase Auth and tries to sign in with email/link, they will automatically be signed in to the same account (eg. linking is done automatically), since the same email is used and both mechanisms of sign in are verified.